# YA horror/suspense book from the 90s

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I'm trying to remember the name of a book I loved when I was a kid. It was set in a castle, with the main character named Jenny, twins named Malcolm and ? and a cousin who acted like a jester ( i think his name was wit?). The twins are actually triplets and the 3rd brother is crazy and haunts the main character. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The book you're describing is [Silent Stalker](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005PWAZ6W) by Richie Tankersley Cusick

> *"Before Jenny Logan even entered the forbidding castle-a replica of the Worthington's ancestral home in England-a terrified stranger
>   warned her away. Was the warning real-or just another example of the
>   family's macabre sense of humor? Jenny couldn't be sure. She only knew
>   her summer vacation with her father suddenly became a nightmare when
>   predatory Sir John Worthington invited them to stay-and his grandsons,
>   the gorgeous Malcolm, his twin Derrick, and their mischievous cousin
>   Wit spun a web of intrigue, romance, and deceit around her. She's
>   forced to play by their rules now, and battle the castle's ancient
>   curse, which decrees that she will go mad, or die...or simply
>   disappear...."*

[image: Silent Stalker]